# Caching with UIImage and downloaded images

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiimage

I have a class method which fetches images with a completion block. This fetched `UIImage` is added to an NSCache with a relevant key. This seems to work as expected, however, in the method which fetches images I am using a `UIImage`'s `imageWithData:` method, which I have discovered does not cache it's data, only `imageNamed:` does.

I am understandably getting memory warnings because of this, how do I make sure the images loaded with `UIImage`'s `imageWithData:` method are removed from memory when not needed anymore?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the method which downloads the images.

```
- (void)imageForFootageSize:(FootageSize)footageSize withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *image))completionBlock
{
    if (completionBlock) {
        __block UIImage *image;

        //  Try getting local image from disk.
        //
        __block NSURL *imageURL = [self localURLForFootageSize:footageSize];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (image) {
                    completionBlock(image);
                } else {
                    //
                    //  Otherwise try getting remote image.
                    //
                    imageURL = [self remoteURLForFootageSize:footageSize];

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                            if (image) {
                                //
                                //  Save remote image to disk
                                //
                                NSURL *photoDirectoryURL = [Footage localURLForDirectory];

                                //      Create the folder(s) where the photos are stored.
                                //
                                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[photoDirectoryURL path] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

                                //      Save photo
                                //
                                NSString *localPath = [[self localURLForFootageSize:footageSize] path];
                                [imageData writeToFile:localPath atomically:YES];
                            }

                            completionBlock(image);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Methods which use the above class method to fetch and process the `UIImage` in the completionHandler.

Method inside `UICollectionViewCell` subclass.

```
- (void)setPhoto:(Photo *)photo withImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    if (photo && !image) {
        [photo imageForFootageSize:[Footage footageSizeThatBestFitsRect:self.bounds]
             withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *image) {
                 if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(galleryPhotoCollectionViewCell:didLoadImage:)]) {
                     [self.delegate galleryPhotoCollectionViewCell:self didLoadImage:image];
                 }

                 image = nil;
             }];
    }

    [self.imageView setImage:image];

    BOOL isPhotoAvailable = (BOOL)(image);

    [self.imageView setHidden:!isPhotoAvailable];
    [self.activityIndicatorView setHidden:isPhotoAvailable];
}
```

Method in `UICollectionView` data source delegate

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DIGalleryPhotoCollectionViewCell *photoCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:photoCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [photoCell setDelegate:self];

    Footage *footage = [self footageForIndexPath:indexPath];
    Photo *photo = ([footage isKindOfClass:[Photo class]]) ? (Photo *)footage : nil;

    if (photo) {
        //
        //  Photo
        //
        [photoCell setPhoto:photo withImage:[self.galleryCache objectForKey:photo.footageID]];
    }

    return photoCell;
}
```

Here are the other relevant methods:

```
- (void)galleryPhotoCollectionViewCell:(DIGalleryPhotoCollectionViewCell *)cell didLoadImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.galleryCollectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

    Footage *footage = [self footageForIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([footage isKindOfClass:[Footage class]]) {
        Photo *photo = (Photo *)footage;

        UIImage *cachedImage = [self.galleryCache objectForKey:photo.footageID];

        if (!cachedImage) {
            cachedImage = image;

            [self.galleryCache setObject:image forKey:photo.footageID];
        }

        [cell setPhoto:photo withImage:image];
    }
}
```

And also my getter method for the `NSCache` property `galleryCache`

```
- (NSCache *)galleryCache
{
    if (!_galleryCache) {
        _galleryCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
    }

    return _galleryCache;
}
```

Comment: See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045412/nscache-holds-strong-pointer-to-uiimage-instantiated-with-imagewithdata-and-doe/23046835#23046835

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own image downloading and caching solution you might be better off using [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). Then you don't have to worry about the downloading, caching or anything. `SDWebImage` also using disk caching so you don't have to worry about freeing memory.

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:imageURL options:0 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
    {
        // progression tracking code
    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
    {
        if (image)
        {
            // do something with image
        }
    }];
```

I'm not sure but you also might have a retain cycle:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[photo imageForFootageSize:[Footage footageSizeThatBestFitsRect:self.bounds] withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *image) {
    if ([weakSelf.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(galleryPhotoCollectionViewCell:didLoadImage:)])
    {
        [weakSelf.delegate galleryPhotoCollectionViewCell:weakSelf didLoadImage:image];
    }
    image = nil;
}];
```

Comment: Surely there must be a more conventional way of doing this? Would it help if I post my code?

Comment: Well there's no point reinvent the wheel :)
But if you want to do it yourself what is the condition when you don't need the image anymore?

Comment: As mentioned the image is added to an `NSCache`, and as you can see in the method I use `imageWithData:` which I believe has very bad memory management. As far as I can see I don't need the downloaded `UIImage` as soon as it's downloaded and added to the `NSCache`

Comment: Where's the `NSCache` in the posted code? If you don't need to show an image set the `UIImageView` `image` to `nil`. As long as you're not retaining the image anywhere it'll be dealloced when its final reference is set to `nil`.

Comment: The `NSCache` isn't used in that code, its used on a higher level, when that method is run it will add that returned `UIImage` in the `completionHandler:` to an NSCache. My problem is that the returned `UIImage` in the `completionHandler:` does not get released at all.

Comment: I have added the methods which use the class method `imageForFootageSize:withCompletionHandler:`

Comment: Try running the static analyser (CMD+Shift+B) - I'm not sure but you might also have a retain cycle in your completion block for `- (void)setPhoto:(Photo *)photo withImage:(UIImage *)image`

Comment: Also added my delegate method.

Comment: Worked through a few potential leaks using analyser. Always forget that feature. Will reply with update soon.

Comment: Despite removing all of the warnings, memory is still never cleaned of `UIImage`s

Comment: This is where I think the retain cycle is:
EDIT, see the answer

Comment: I've just tried your code but it gives the same results. Any other ideas?

Comment: How big are you images?

Comment: From 180x180 up to 1200 x 1200 or more

Comment: Using your `weakSelf` code along with making the `image` variable (in imageForFootageSize:...) a weak variable does help with memory, however the time it takes to load images is n times slower.

Comment: I think my issue is inside the delegate method which updates my `NSCache` as it saves the same image into the cache

Comment: You might also want to change the `image` parameter name to something else in the `withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *image)` as it matches the method `image` parameter in `- (void)setPhoto:(Photo *)photo withImage:(UIImage *)image`

Comment: Nice suggestion, unfortunately it's not the solution